# Field excitement in quantum field theory?

Tags: magnetic-field, early-universe, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

How at the beginning of this universe the fields as proposed in quantum fields theory get excited??
How exactly these fields originated?

Comment: This sounds like a physics question more than Astronomy, and I'm not sure it's an answerable physics question either.

Comment: Because it was possible? This could even become a metaphysical question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this question is one which is under active -- and so far fruitless -- investigation by the theoretical physics community.  Anyone who could answer it would have the choice of publishing here and getting +450 reputation or so, and a couple of badges. Or they could publish in *Nature* of *Phys Rev* and get at least one Nobel Prize.

Bottom line: No one knows yet.